# What is Ferb's name short for?

Tags: phineas-and-ferb

Everytime Ferb wants to say how his full name sounds like, he gets interrupted. When Vanessa asked Candace what Ferb's full name is, Candace couldn't reply anything indicating that she also doesn't know.

So what is Ferb's full name?

Answer (score 15):

As answered on [the relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferb_Fletcher):

> Ferb was named after a set-builder named Frank Leasure, a construction foreman on several *Star Trek* properties and a friend of Povenmire and Marsh. His wife Melinda, an artist on *The Simpsons* and *King of the Hill* nicknamed him "Ferb". In "Vanessassary Roughness" Ferb explains that his name is short for something, but he didn't get to say it. **On Twitter, Povenmire announced that Ferb was actually short for "Ferbs".**

While the Wikipedia page doesn't link to that tweet, it most likely refers to [this one from 30 Augustus 2015](https://twitter.com/DanPovenmire/status/637979638539489280):

> Nope, sorry. It is "Ferbs" from Act Your Age.

(He is referring to [the episode of that name](https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/Act_Your_Age).)

This was in response to a reply to [an earlier tweet from 17 August 2015](https://twitter.com/DanPovenmire/status/633053879140114432):

> I'm going to say something we've never said publicly, the name that "Ferb" is short for has already been said in the series.

Comment: Ah yes, the ol' "Homer Jay Simpson" trick...

Comment: Vanessa does call him "Ferbs" in "Act Your Age", so if the tweet is to be taken seroiusly, at some point in the next 8-10 years she figures it out. Of course, if the tweet came after that episode (2015), then this could have been unintentional or retconned.